# how to keep multiple select_tag values after refresh?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I keep the selected values of my multiple select_tag after refresh?

```
<%= select_tag(:cars, options_for_select( [['bmw', 50000], ['audi', 55000], ['fiat', 20000], 0    ), :multiple => true,  :title=> "All Makes", :class => "selectpicker input-small" )  %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass list of selected values as second option to the `options_for_select`:

```
<%= select_tag(:cars,
               options_for_select([['bmw', 50000], 
                                   ['audi', 55000],
                                   ['fiat', 20000]],
                                  [55000, 50000]), 
               :multiple => true,  :title=> "All Makes",
               :class => "selectpicker input-small" )  %>
```

In this case `bmw` and `audi` options will be selected.

More information see in the API reference [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select).